# In Linux: How to get the device name of a USB port after a thumb drive has been inserted into it?

Tags: linux, usb

I have several USB ports on the front of my computer, and when I insert a thumb drive into one of them, it gets mounted temporarily in /media. I can navigate to its mount point directory in /media and treat it like any other directory, but for what I am trying to do, I need the thumb drive's /dev/___ name. How can I obtain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its mounted to /media, the easiest trick is to just say

```
df /media/path
```

it will give you the /dev fs its mounted on

---

For more details you could do, (saving output to a file)

```
sudo lshw
```

and, look for the "`/media/path`" section in the output.
That will give you the association with more details.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there had to be some kind of command, but my Googlefu wasn't good enough to find it. df works perfectly.

Comment: I did an inverted lookup :-) recalling I always saw that detail when using `df`.

Comment: If it isn't mounted to media, then "fdisk -l | grep sd" will show the essentials, without scrolling off the screen if you have a lot of drives connected.

Answer (score 1):

lsusb will do the trick.